# Reading a txt file in C

Tags: c, parsing, text-files

I have a txt file called coords.TXT, which shows the following:

```
4900N 5350W
4830N 4900W
5000N 4900W
6000N 5830W
```

Now I want to have a c program that reads this csv file and prints out an output

```
Longitude,Latitude: 3900N,5350W
Longitude,Latitude: 4830N,4900W
Longitude,Latitude: 5000N,4900W
Longitude,Latitude: 6000N,5830W
Longitude,Latitude: 6000N,5830W
```

However when I run the program it does not seem to want to copy things completely and I get the output:

```
Longitude,Latitude: 900N,5350W
Longitude,Latitude: 4830N,4900W
Longitude,Latitude: 5000N,4900W
Longitude,Latitude: 6000N,5830W
Longitude,Latitude: 6000N,5830W
```

Here is a snippet of my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
    {
        /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
        printf( "usage: ./a.out filename\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
        FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

        /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
        if ( file == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Could not open file\n" );
        }
        else 
        {
            char data;
            char x[5];
            char y[5];

            /* read one character at a time from file, stopping at EOF, which
               indicates the end of the file.  Note that the idiom of "assign
               to a variable, check the value" used below works because
               the assignment statement evaluates to the value assigned. */
            while  ( ( data = fgetc( file ) ) != EOF )
            {
                fscanf(file,"%s %s",&x,&y);
                printf("Longitude,Latitude: %s,%s\n",x,y);
            }
            fclose( file );
        }
    }
}
```

I also want it set up so I can assign the numbers with N by them to a variable lat and the numbers with a W to a variable lon.  Any ideas?

Comment: You know the answer because it's written in your code as a comment.

Comment: Please search this site using the search phrase `[c] read text file` (including the brackets). There are literally dozens of questions that discuss reading data from text files using that language here already; certainly one of them can help you.

Comment: The x and y arrays should be of length 6 and not 5 because you need  one byte for the terminating zero. But even with length 6 this is dangerous, because if the input file does not strictly conform to the format of your coords.TXT file you will get a buffer overflow for the x and y arrays. You should use `fgets` to read one whole line of text and parse this line by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You call `fgetc` to read one character, which you then throw away.

Also, your comparison is broken. You need to compare the return value of `fgets` to `EOF`, but instead you compare the return value of an assignment.

That doesn't work for the same reason this doesn't work:

```
int j;
if ((j = 3.2) == 3.2)
```

The result of `j = 3.2` is an integer, which won't be `3.2`. Similarly, the result of `data = fgetc( file )` will be a character which won't be EOF. EOF is not a character, just as 3.2 is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `fgetc(file)` it's eating a character each time it's called. the first character it eats is your '4'. Every other time you get lucky and it eats a space (which `fscanf` would have just thrown out anyway.) So instead of testing if the file is good by doing an `fgetc` you should try using something like this:

```
while(fscanf(file,"%s %s",&x,&y) == 2){
    printf("Longitude,Latitude: %s,%s\n",x,y);
}
```

Comment: Better to compare against the only desired return value  `fscanf(file,"%s %s",&x,&y) == 2` rather than one of the possible undesired return values like `EOF`.

Comment: @chux Not that anyone but you will notice this post, but that's a really good comment. Thanks.

Comment: Yes noticed just now that it is a year old post.

Comment: @chux Whatever it's the right way to do things maybe someone somewhere will benefit :)